# I was learning about Node.js and npm and made this error and now I can't resolve this

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-package

Current Node version:- 18.12.1

Current npm version :- 5.5.1

Operating System :- Ubuntu 22.04

I am learning backend and I was specifically learning about npm,the instructor recommended me to downgrade my node version to follow along with him better and smoothly, I did it and now I am unable to install any package and I am getting this error again and again.

```
"03_Node_Package_Manager$ npm i -g node@8.9.1

npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v18.12.1

npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we

npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.

npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.

npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/

WARNING: You are likely using a version of node-tar or npm that is incompatible with this      version of Node.js.

Please use either the version of npm that is bundled with Node.js, or a version of npm (> 5.5.1  or < 5.4.0) or node-tar (> 4.0.1) that is compatible with Node.js 9 and above.

npm[73891]: ../src/node_zlib.cc:584:static void node::{anonymous}::ZlibStream::Init(const     v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&): Assertion `args.Length() == 7 && "init(windowBits, level, memLevel, strategy, writeResult, writeCallback," " dictionary)"' failed.

1: 0xb6e500 node::Abort() [npm]

2: 0xb6e57e [npm]

3: 0xc3b42a [npm]

4: 0xda5fa0 [npm]

5: 0xda74df v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [npm]

6: 0x16e9af9 [npm]

Aborted (core dumped)"
```

I am trying relentlessly to delete this version of npm but I am unable to do so because this version of npm doesn't go along with this version of node and isn't allowing me to delete and neither allowing me to downgrade my version of node either.

I also deleted the files of npm,but the error is still there,can anyone help me out,I an stuck on it for hours now.

Comment: You can uninstall node (and npm) and then install node 8 fresh.  Then show your instructor this message:  "Excuse me, instructor, respectfully, this is computer science class, not history class.  Please do not force your class to use software whose long term service ended in 2019.  Node 8 is a _woolly mammoth meatball_.  Sincerely -- the internet".

Answer (score 0):

You could try to uninstall `npm` and install it by using the below commands.

```
sudo apt remove -y npm

sudo apt install -y npm
```

If the above didn't work you could uninstall the `Node JS` and install it from scratch again.

```
sudo apt uninstall -y nodejs

sudo apt install -y nodejs
```

for more details, visit this [Install / Uninstall Node JS in ubuntu 22.04](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/install-nodejs-on-ubuntu-22-04/)

I would suggest you to install `Node` via `NVM` (Node Version Manager). It is basically a version management tool for Node JS.

[Installing NVM in ubuntu 22.04](https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-nvm-on-ubuntu-22-04/?amp)

[NVM Commands Cheatsheet](https://duncanleung.com/nvm-commands-cheatsheet/)